# Replacement of symsum

Tags: matlab, cvx

What replacement can we use instead of symsum in a [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) code in Matlab?
I want to use a double summation without using a loop, and symsum seems to be the only available option.

Comment: Show your code. Or an example of what you mean. Are you summing to to infinity or to a fixed value? I assume that `symsum` returns a numeric result rather than a closed form expression for your summation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to vectorize your function, using `sum` is the fastest possibility:

```
sum([1:10].^2) %sum all squares from 1 to 10
```

If this is not possible, combine arrayfun and sum:

```
f=@(x)(x^2)
sum(arrayfun(f,1:10))%sum all squares from 1 to 10
```